# Get complete Amazon MQ queue name inside AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-mq

I am using Amazon MQ as my MQTT broker and have used it as a trigger for my AWS-Lambda function.

A message is published on the AmazonMQ's queue name: `device.pir_5.property.alert`.

The Lambda trigger subscribes to the queue on: `device.*.property.*`

The lambda function is successfully triggered when a message is published on the above topic. But I am not able to receive the complete queue name. In the payload I receive inside the lambda function I can see the queue name as: `destination.physicalName: device.*.property.*`

I do not have control over what is being published in the payload and I need to access the deviceId from the queue name itself. Is there a way to find the complete AmazonMQ queue name inside the Lambda? Appreciate your help!

I tried giving the lambda trigger full access to Amazon MQ by adding the permission: `AmazonMQFullAccess`. I am not sure if it's an issue with AWS permissions.